# Typewriter effect

Tags: html, css

So I got the typewriter effect to work but when I do it it only does it once and I want it to be continuous and I want to make sure the blinking cursor isn't visible. I want the same text just I want it to be in a loop going back and forth. Here is the code

```css
.typewriter {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the text is not visible until animation starts */
  border-right: 0.15em solid orange;
  /* Creates the blinking cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the text on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Centers the element */
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  /* Adds a slight space between characters */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret 0.75s step-end infinite;
  /* Sets the animation for the typing and blinking cursor */
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  /* Starts with no width */
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* Increases width to 100% */
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  /* Starts and ends with transparent border */
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
  /* Changes border color to orange at 50% */
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1 style="font-size: 26px">Food Made With Love</h1>

  <p style="font-size: 18px">
    Goo's Delights is a modern Boulder hotspot. Originally opened in 2015, Goo's Delights has been given numerous awards displaying their outstanding service and commitment to quality food. Goo's Delights is commited to bringing the community together, all
    while providing the best food possible. Contact us for more info.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `interation-count` `infinite` to both `typing` and `blink-caret` animations.
You can use `alternate` if you want to restart the animation from the backword direction.

```css
.typewriter {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the text is not visible until animation starts */
  border-right: 0.15em solid orange;
  /* Creates the blinking cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the text on a single line */
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  /* Centers the element */
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  /* Adds a slight space between characters */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end) infinite alternate, blink-caret 0.75s step-end infinite alternate;
  /* Sets the animation for the typing and blinking cursor */
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  /* Starts with no width */
  to {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: fit-content;
  }
  /* Increases width to 100% */
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  /* Starts and ends with transparent border */
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
  /* Changes border color to orange at 50% */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 style="font-size: 26px">Food Made With Love</h1>

  <p style="font-size: 18px" class="typewriter">
    Goo's Delights is a modern Boulder hotspot. Originally opened in 2015, Goo's Delights has been given numerous awards displaying their outstanding service and commitment to quality food. Goo's Delights is commited to bringing the community together, all
    while providing the best food possible. Contact us for more info.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how I would be make it so that the cursor only goes over the words and not over the entire screen. And also make it so that when the tyepwriter effect takes place the words will stay in one place and not move to the left of the screen.

Comment: @SwayamJain remove the `margin: 0 auto` style property from `typewriter` class. and apply `typewriter` class only to texts. I've updated the code.

Comment: Thank you for the help. One more question how do I make the typewriter effect occur faster. Right now the effect occurs and then it stops and the blinker goes to the right of the screen and then 10 seconds later it comes back and does it. How do i make the blinker only go over the text and not across the whole screen.